# Difference between Areca, Chamaedorea and Kentia in appearance

Tags: identification, houseplants

Areca and Chamaedorea and Kentia are very similar. Whats difference between them in appearance. In the other word how can recognize each of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kentia ([Howea forsteriana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howea_forsteriana)) are normally sold as larger plants ranging from 3' to 6' or more (1 - 3 M).  They have stems that are normally 1" (2 cm) or more in diameter at the base and have a fibrous husk from older stems at the base.  Leaves are pinnate and a dark waxy green with 25 or 30 leaflets on a large stem. These are among the more expensive plants to buy as they grow slowly. Pests include scale, [Boisduval false scale](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/orn/scales/boisduval_scale.htm) and the odd bit of mealybug. I have never seen it flower or fruit when grown indoors.

Areca palms (Chrysalidocarpus lutescens, [Dypsis lutescens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dypsis_lutescens)) are said to grow 12M tall but this must be in the tropics.  I have seen them sold as 6" tall plants for fish tanks and 6' (2 M) specimens for larger interiorscapes.  Foliage is pinnate but smaller than a Kentia with thinner leaves and a lighter green colour, sometimes with a yellowish tinge. There are more leaflets per stem, up to 50 or 60 on a large one. When it flowers branching, yellow flower stalks emerge from below the leaves and droop downward. In lower light levels these dry quickly to a light brown. Smaller specimens are magnets for spider mites.

Bamboo palms are sometimes called [Chamaedorea seifrizii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamaedorea) and are very common. Foliage also consists of thin pinnate leaves.  They tend to be thinner than Areca palms of the same height and more of a cylindrical shape.  They flower indoors and the fruit is an orange or red drupe which turns black.  The stems are usually one half inch or 1 cm in diameter. One identification is the dead light brown leaf sheaths that are found on the stems.  Leaf sheaths are all at the base. Pests are spider mites, mealy bug, thrip and rarely scale.